# Transistors replacement

Tags: transistors, npn, pnp

Can I safely replace `2N3904` and `2N3906` with `BC337` and `BC327` in an audio amplifier circuit since both pairs are `NPN`, `PNP`?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJnPNf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It's impossible to say based on the information provided. You'd have to at least supply a schematic diagram. Certainly, they are all low-power, general-purpose transistors, so it's likely that it would just work, but you need to compare the specifications against the application requirements to be sure.

Comment: @DaveTweed I added the circuit.

Comment: This isn't an amplifier, it's a 20dB attenuator, and with immense crossover distortion. No output at all between +-0.7V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to add a few thoughts about your schematic, itself, as well. There are a few questions and problems that I see (as a hobbyist.)

1. You don't specify what your input signal looks like. Without that information it is difficult to say much at all about the circuit. The gain shown is about \$100\times\$, which may be too high, too low, or just right. No way to tell. But for now, let's assume it is just right and move on.
2. Assuming you really do need that gain and that the BJTs are driving close to the rails (let's say no closer than \$1V\$, though, so that they stay out of saturation), they each will be delivering about \$P_{load}=\frac{V_{peak}^2=5V^2}{2\cdot 8\Omega}\approx 1.5 W\$ into the load speaker. Since optimal delivery of power into a load requires a source impedance that is about the same, an efficient linear amplifier design can at best hope to deliver \$1.5 W\$ by itself dissipating the same amount. So each of your output BJTs will be picking up at least \$P_{bjt}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 1.5W = 750mW\$. This will require packaging that is NOT a TO-92, but instead a TO-220 style.
3. Each BJT might be expected to supply \$I_{C_{peak}}=\frac{V_{peak}=5V}{8\Omega}=625mA\$. You also need to make sure that the selected BJTs are specified to supply \$I_C\ge 1A\$. \$I_C=2A\$ would be even better to see on the datasheet.
4. The base current for each BJT will be, because they are staying out of saturation (per my earlier estimation above), on the order of a factor of \$\beta \ge 50\$ lower. So you must expect that the opamp itself can supply at least \$20mA\$ at its output, just to be safe. The LM741 has a short-circuit output of about \$25mA\$. So you are near the margins here. But I think it will be okay because although I estimated \$\beta \approx 50\$ here, you may get as much as \$3-5\times\$ better than that depending on the output BJT and its operating point. So let's assume it is okay for now.
5. The LM741 also has a problem reaching its rails. Let's say your LM741 is required to supply \$I_{peak}=10mA\$ to your BJTs. Assuming it can reach to the rails (it cannot even come close to that), this implies an effective load of about \$\frac{6V}{10mA}=600\Omega\$. However, the datasheet says that even with a lighter load of only \$2k\Omega\$ the best you can be absolutely sure of is that it can come within about \$5V\$ of a \$15V\$ rail, or about \$10V\$. They do say that it typically can get closer -- perhaps within \$2V\$ of the rails. But no matter how you look at it, this opamp isn't going to come close to your rails. So this means you cannot expect to see even \$V_{peak}=5V\$ on your speakers. If we go with a drop of \$3V\$ at the opamp output, plus another diode drop for the BJT emitter, you are looking at a maximum \$V_{peak}=2V\$ or so. This suggests only \$\frac{1}{4}W\$ of output. And an even smaller input signal acceptance, given the gain programmed into your circuit. On the good side, this means that your BJTs could just be TO-92 packaged parts and you can use small signal devices there (assuming they can still provide \$\frac{2V}{8\Omega} = 250mA\$ of collector current.) But only if you changed your voltage rail to the BJTs. If you can't (and I have no reason to believe you can), then those BJTs will still dissipate the same as before. So forget the small signal BJT entirely without changing your whole design and goals. This means you might want to look for a different, rail to rail output type, opamp.
6. Now that we've decided that your output is sorely limited to a much smaller output power, your circuit's very significant cross-over distortion will now be *terrible* and, I'm pretty sure, quite noticeable. You really need a different arrangement to drive those two BJTs, stuck with that LM741. Here I'm thinking of a pair of diodes (optionally tied thermally to your BJTs) and using the opamp to sink a current mirror's current through them.
7. You may want to include a small capacitor to help stabilize your voltage divider's mid-point value. Given the substantial input currents used by the LM741, your resistor divider impedance will probably have an impact on the output, as well. I may consider putting a cap there.

I can provide a more specific arrangement for you, based on your existing idea but where these details are accounted. But given that I have no idea what you are using to feed the amplifier as a signal, no idea what kind of 12V power source you are using, and no idea what kind of output power you want, it's really hard to do much more than the above commentary.

ADDED:

Just by way of reference, here's a first improvement step. It's not complete. But it's better. I've left off some of the specific quantities or device numbers, as that's not my point. But I've used specific values to get across some ideas:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZOGnL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The current mirror uses a pair of BJTs that are thermally linked (in the same package) as a BCV62. With the value of \$R_{set}=3.3k\Omega\$ (probably the largest value you should try, as it produces the lowest viable set current you should use), the current available for the output BJT bases will be about \$3.2mA\$ or so. This is enough to keep the diodes with active drops, as well. (Those diodes should probably be thermally coupled to the two output BJTs, as well.) The opamp should be one capable of getting down to within \$\frac{1}{2}V\$ of its (-) rail, or better. (The upper rail has a lesser requirement due to the two diodes.)

This isn't a design. It's just a direction to head to help increase your output power to the load and to reduce (or nearly eliminate, if the BJTs can both be kept ON throughout it) cross-over distortion. It's gain here is set to \$\frac{R_{fb}}{R_{in}}=10\$. This is not what your original circuit shows. It's just a value I chose, for now.

Comment: Gain is ~1/10. Power is calculated from VRMS which is ~3.5V here.

Comment: @EJP: No. The circuit provided by the OP doesn't appear to me to have a gain of \$\frac{1}{10}\$. Not sure where that comes from. Also, given the LM731 rail limits and keeping the BJTs out of saturation, it's unlikely the OP circuit sees more than \$V_{peak}\approx 3V\$ or about \$V_{RMS}\approx 2V\$. How did you get your figure?

Comment: The gain of an inverting op-amp circuit is given by by -Rf/Rin or -R4/R1. -1/10, or -20dB ignoring the inversion. Not sure where you get 100 from. My RMS figure comes from your peak figure. You first used 5V peak, that is ~3.5VRMS. The point is that you are misusing Ohm's law, not just here but everywhere.

Comment: @EJP: The gain comes from the ratio of \$R_4\$ and \$R_1\$ in his diagram. Unless I'm reading them wrong, I get \$\frac{10k}{100}\approx 100\$. (Assuming of course that the input capacitor \$C_1\$ has low impedance relative to signal frequencies, of course.)

Comment: @EJP: No, not misusing it at all. I mentioned \$5V\$ assuming that he used a rail to rail. He's not, so he's not getting that.

Comment: You are misusing Ohm's Law for AC if you are using peak instead of RMS.

Comment: @EJP: You don't even seem to understand why I derated the output, given the LM741, from \$V_{peak}=5V\$ to around \$2-3V\$. And you don't seem, also, to understand why the circuit as shown will attempt to exhibit a gain of 100, with small enough input signals and assuming a low impedance driver. I've no idea where to go from here. If you want to say anything more, I propose we take this to chat and resolve it thoroughly and that you get your simulator ready, as well. (I've verified my comments and analysis already, given this discussion, just to be add some confirmation.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they should work okay. They are rated for higher current and voltage isn't an issue.

Either pair has the potential of overheating in that particular circuit, and that's a particularly nasty audio amplifier circuit with no biasing of the output transistors, so you will get gobs of crossover distortion with a slow op-amp like a 741.

Don't forget to allow for the different transistor pinouts! Eg.

> 2N3904: E-B-C
>    BC337:  C-B-E

---

Edit: Re crossover distortion see the following two simulations with different op-amps, to illustrate @curd's point in the comment. I'm not suggesting using a 100MHz op-amp in this application, but it does illustrate how a bad output circuit can make an okay-for-audio op-amp like the 741 behave much worse than necessary.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsc2sc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

There is still a slight kink in the circuit with the AD797, but it is far more pronounced on the 741 circuit. Because the crossover is inside the negative feedback loop, the op-amp will try to negate it, but the output of the op-amp can only slew so fast, so that dead zone of +.6 to -.6V at the op-amp output takes some time to transition. It's not so important (though it looks much worse) at, say, 10kHz because there is no audible difference to humans between a 10kHz square wave and a sine wave. At 1kHz, on the other hand, the harmonics at 3kHz will be annoyingly audible.

It's preferable to bias the transistors as shown [here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amp_6.html):

[image]

But the circuit shown will produce sound at the output and is simpler (and less prone to possible problems if the bias resistors are wrong).

Comment: If @jonk calculations are right (and I have no reason to doubt that), then these BJTs are not suited for this circuit, since their maximum collect current is only 200 mA.

Comment: WT<beep>! He has 3904/6 and wants to use the 800 mA BC337. I got it all backwards. Well, maybe h has to replace the 2n390x because they were fried...

Comment: You will get gobs of crossover distortion with any opamp. The output is off between +/-0.7V.

Comment: @EJP: you are wrong. Although it'd be better to add diodes at each base to get pos./neg offsets for the bases of the NPN/PNP it is not as bad as you think because the feedback (right terminal of R4) comes from the **output** (emitters) of the transistors. The OpAmp will try to do whatever is neccesarry to bring **that** point to the desired voltage. It will just take a tiny little bit longer near +/- 0.7V and since we can assume that this amplifier is not supposed to deliver HiFi quality it's ok.

Answer (score -1):

The BCxxx parts you selected, come in a TO-92 plastic package which are underrated for this power requirement.  The 2Nx390x parts come in a TO-88 package rated for higher mW/deg C. THis indicates (inverse of) junction temperature rise above ambient per mW of power dissipated.

When selecting equivalent or better, this factor is important to prevent frying parts.  You should get "better than" original specs using bigger parts with highest hFE for current gain available or use higher impedance earphones.

Comment: 2N390x are TO-92, too.